# Is that a good idea to keep user's IP address in database table "user"? Or where it should be kept?

Tags: database, ip

I am creating a database for IS, so where should I keep user's IP address - in a table "users" or somewhere else? (for example, "comments" table etc)

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are planning to use it for. It probably doesn't make sense to store it as data about a user though - it will almost certainly change from time to time.

Comment: As a user, I want to log in to your site from home, office, my mobile phone, wifi at a coffee shop, etc etc. They will all have different IPs. What are you using this IP address for? Have you considered that for any given user it is very likely to change from one session to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the IP of the user is a security measure to protect againts [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), so it makes sense that you store it inside your session. If sessions are saved in the database, the `session` table is the place where I would add the `IP` column.

Comment: Is he trying to use it to prevent session hijacking? Is he using session at all?

Comment: This is not specified (but I guess 1: no and 2: maybe). Still he could benefit from this piece of information even if it weren't his original intention

Comment: Yeah, of course, he can benefit from it and you had a valid input I was just struggling to relate that to his one-size-fit-all abstract question, I thought that maybe you knew what he was trying to achieve

Comment: Anyway,  it's question that deserve a zillion answers

Comment: In fact I have no idea of his requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the essence and the meaning this data holds in the system. As long as you know that a client with DHCP configuration might have a different IP address every time he access your site